# How to get the checked items of checkboxes created dynamically and write that value to a file in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, checkbox

I have written a WPF Application in C# to create checkboxes during runtime as the contents must be obtained from a file. The user selects the items from the checkbox. On the click of a button, all the checked items must be written to a text file. How can it be done?
Is the following code correct way to create checkboxes dynamically?

```
CheckBox chb;
private void radioButton2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Create file
    string fp5 = @"D:\List.txt";       

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fp5, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

    float cby = 135.0F;
    int ControlIndex=1;

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        chb = new CheckBox();
        chb.Name = "Chk" + ControlIndex;
        Canvas.SetLeft(chb, 28);
        Canvas.SetTop(chb, cby);
        chb.Content = line;
        chb.IsChecked = false;
        chb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        myCanvas.Children.Add(chb);
        cby = cby + 25.0F;
        ControlIndex++;
    }
    fs.Close();
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Create files
    string fp6 = @"D:\List2.txt";

    if (!File.Exists(fp6))
    File.Create(fp6).Close();

    /*I want to write the checked items of the checkbox chb to the text file List2.txt.
    I wanted to know how to do this */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 string str="";
 foreach (UIElement child in canvas.Children)
 {
   if(child  is CheckBox)
     if(((CheckBox)child).IsChecked)
       str+=((CheckBox)child).Content;

 }
 string fp6 = @"D:\List2.txt";
 File.WriteAllText(fp6,str);

}
```